# In <select> `select as label for (key , value) in object` not wokrking when `select` returns new data

Tags: angularjs

## Abstract

I have [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0p96LgOTZN6QCtFZJJg?p=preview) where I need to preprocess values selected from `<select multiple></select>`

One may need `<select>` to return new (unbound) data when `<select>` was previously bound to partial data. For example such partial data may be a list of `id`s, and after selecting one (or many) `id`s one may need his `ngModel` to get populated with values that are (for example) loaded from server.

## Question

What am I doing wrong? Why when returning a new value(the one that wasn't bound by `<select>`) from `select` expression of `ngOptions`, I'm unable to select any item within `<select>`

## Thank you!

---

## Edit

In simple words, there is standard declaration:

```
<select ng-model="color" multiple ng-options="c as c.name for (k,c) in colors"></select>
```

where `ng-options` are:

```
c as c.name for (k,c) in colors
```

These `ng-options` will result with `c` in `ng-model`, but what I need is:

```
load(c) as c.name for (k,c) in colors
```

The result of `load` is an object other than `c`, in my example this other object is created the following way:

```
$scope.load = function (c) {
    return {
        color: c,
        now: new Date()
    }
}
```

When load returns new object, `<select>` control stops working, it makes `<select>` unable to   select several values (with `ctrl` pressed). You are able to see this behaviour in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0p96LgOTZN6QCtFZJJg?p=preview)

Comment: hard to make sens out of your objective from the limited demo. My guess is you could use an event like `ng-change` to bind the select data to some other data in app. Just not clear what you want to bind to

Comment: This what you're looking for? [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/osDZL9r6dPrBtGzB3Hy3?p=preview). I just modified how you saved the data.

Comment: Zack, I need to modify selected value as described in `$scope.load` function, when I do that, select stops working

Comment: I have updated my plunk to make it more clear to see the problem